# Woocommerce sql products orders prices

Tags: sql, wordpress

```
select
 
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_product_id' and p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as "Id",
p.order_item_name as "Product Name",
max( CASE WHEN wppm.meta_key = '_regular_price' and wpp.ID = wppm.post_id and wpp.ID = p.order_id THEN wppm.meta_value END ) as "Regular Prices",
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_qty' and p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as "qty",
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_line_total' and p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as "Gross",
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_line_subtotal_tax' and p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as subTotalTax,
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_line_tax' and p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as Tax,
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_tax_class' and p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as taxClass,
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_line_subtotal' and p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as subtotal
from
wp_woocommerce_order_items as p,
wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as pm,
wp_posts as wpp,
wp_postmeta as wppm
 where order_item_type = 'line_item' and

 p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id 
 and wpp.ID = wppm.post_id
AND wpp.ID = p.order_id

 
 group by
p.order_item_id
```

All column result are ok but begular price is null, how can i fix it?
How can I calculate a total for quantity?

Comment: I guess pm.meta_key = '_regular_price' instead of wppm.meta_key = '_regular_price'

Comment: I changed and still null.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot speak to your particular problem, but the query should be structured as:

```
select max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_product_id' THEN pm.meta_value END ) as "Id",
       p.order_item_name as "Product Name",
       max( CASE WHEN wppm.meta_key = '_regular_price' and wpp.ID = wppm.post_id and wpp.ID = p.order_id THEN wppm.meta_value END ) as "Regular Prices",
       max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_qty' THEN pm.meta_value END ) as "qty",
       max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_line_total' THEN pm.meta_value END ) as "Gross",
       max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_line_subtotal_tax' THEN pm.meta_value END ) as subTotalTax,
       max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_line_tax' THEN pm.meta_value END ) as Tax,
       max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_tax_class' THEN pm.meta_value END ) as taxClass,
       max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_line_subtotal' THEN pm.meta_value END ) as subtotal
from wp_woocommerce_order_items p join
     wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta pm
     on p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id join
     wp_posts wpp
     on wpp.ID = p.order_id join
     wp_postmeta as wppm
     on wpp.ID = wppm.post_id
where order_item_type = 'line_item'
group by p.order_item_id;
```

Notes:

- Use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.
- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- The condition `and p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id` is not needed in the `case` expression.

I also suspect that your query is generating a Cartesian product.  Once again, that won't affect your results, it just slows down the query.  However, you have not provided sample data and desired results, so that is not 100% certain.

I don't think this will fix your particular problem.  But presumably `'_regular_price'` is not available as a key value in `wppm`.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, I am still null for the price.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/214686/woocommerce-query-for-ordered-products here I found correct, but adding column with prices still causes an error.

Comment: @Jacko21 . . . You need to investigate what the exact tag is.  Or perhaps your system is not storing the tag you need.